# ArcGIS for Java: Event when layer is completely loaded

Tags: arcgis

I'm new to the development of **ArcGIS for Java**. Currently, I've got an application which creates a JMap and loads 3 layers:

1. ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer (World_Imagery)
2. ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer (World_Transportation)
3. GraphicsLayer to display some GPS-Points as Polylines

When all the map content is **fully loaded**, I want to save the map as an image. At the moment this is done by writing a bufferedImage to a file. Because in future the application should run automatically in backgorund, without showing the JFrame, I need some sort of event, signalizing when all content is loaded.

I searched the API-Reference, but couldn't find anything.

Is there any chance to get the correct moment, when all the work is done? Is there a more elegant way to save the map as an image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all people encountering the same problem, there is the **ProgressEvent**,  "which is fired by the map and indicates the draw progress of the Map's layer collection"

Therefore, saving the fully loaded map as an image is possible, when the progress has reached 100 %:

```
jMap.addProgressEventListener(new ProgressEventListener()
{
     @Override
     public void progress(ProgressEvent event) 
     {
          System.out.println(event.getProgress());
          if(event.getProgress() == 100)
          {
              SaveMap((JComponent) appWindow.getComponent(0));
          }
     }
});
```